# MySQL InnoDB Error 1114 Table is full when importing dump

Tags: mysql, database

MySQL version is 5.7.9. OS windows 7 SP1, 32 bit, NTFS.

I have a large dump in which an innodb table is of around 60 million records in it. After importing, when the table file is larger than 4GB, the Error 1114 will appear. However, the importing continues. When finished, the file grows to 10 GB. Apparently, some data got lost.

I have two partitions. C is with 12 GB free and D is with 300 GB free. The database file is on drive D. And the tmp dir is also on drive D. Both with the TMPDIR env variable and the TMPDIR setting in configuration file.

My configuration file is as follows.

Anyone can give a suggestion?

Thanks.

```
[client]
no-beep
port=3306
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir="D:/Database/Data"
tmpdir="D:/tmp"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:1G:autoextend
innodb_temp_data_file_path=ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="ttt.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="ttt.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="ttt.err"
server-id=1
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"
max_connections=151
query_cache_size=0
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=13M
thread_cache_size=10

#*** MyISAM Specific options
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=17M
key_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=34K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

#*** INNODB Specific options ***
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
innodb_log_file_size=20G
innodb_log_files_in_group=3
innodb_thread_concurrency=9
innodb_autoextend_increment=512
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet=16M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=4161
query_cache_type=0
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
wait_timeout=28800
interactive_timeout=28800
```

Comment: is the database, or D:\ , running on a FAT32 filesystem? :/

Comment: No, all are NTFS. That's why I think weird. I also copied the dump to D which is 6 GB. The oddest thing is when the table exceeds 4 GB there is such error however it can keep on growing.

Comment: are you doing everything in 1 huge transaction? try committing every few inserts, maybe it hits a transaction-size-limit (they exists)

Comment: Hi, how to do that? I just dump the big table by mysqldump  --no-autocommit. Any other options can enforce a commit after several insert?

Comment: Finally, when I move to Win 7 64 bit and add innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0, the problem resolved.